# Are all problems in NP which are not P NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory

1. Are all problems in NP which are not P NP-complete?
   To make myself more clear, is NP-P=NPC? If not, can you give an example of an NP problem that is neither P nor NP-complete?
2. Are all NP-complete problems NP-hard?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This may be more appropriate on one of the stack exchange sites. See this [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/are-there-np-problems-not-in-p-and-not-np-complete).  It seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

First, a picture

[image]

1. [Problems in NP not known to be in P or NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Problems_in_NP_not_known_to_be_in_P_or_NP-complete)

> It was shown by Ladner that if `P ≠ NP` then there exist problems in `NP`
>   that are neither in `P` nor `NP-complete`. Such problems are called
>   `NP-intermediate` problems. The [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), the [discrete
>   logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and the [integer factorization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) are examples
>   of problems believed to be `NP-intermediate`. They are some of the very
>   few `NP` problems not known to be in `P` or to be `NP-complete`.

2. `NP-hard` is a class of problems which are at least as hard as the hardest problems in `NP`. Thus, yes, every `NP-complete` problem is `NP-hard`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, the answer depends on whether P = NP. If P = NP, then there aren't any problems in NP that aren't in P, so no such problems exist. On the other hand, if P ≠ NP, then a result called [Ladner's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate) guarantees that there are problems that are in NP, not in P, and not NP-complete (these are called NP-intermediate problems). The proof of this theorem works by constructing highly contrived languages that meet all the criteria. We don't know of any specific problems right now that are NP-intermediate, since if we knew of any we'd have proven that P ≠ NP.

For you second question, yes, by definition all NP-complete problems are NP-hard. The NP-complete problems are defined to be the NP-hard problems that are also in class NP.

Answer (score 1):

I can only definitely answer 2.

NP-hardness is required for NP-completeness, as by its definition. A problem *H* is said to be NP-complete if all problems in NP can be reduced to it in polynomial time. Therefore, it will be at least as hard to solve *H*, as it is to solve any other problem in NP which is the definition of NP-hardness.